# Dealing with Padding / Stuff Bits Entropy Encoded JPEG

Tags: jpeg, huffman-code

When [decoding entropy encoded DC values in JPEG](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-huffman-coding.html) (or the [entropy encoded prediction differences in lossless JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_JPEG)), how do I distinguish between `1` bits that have been stuffed to pad a byte before a marker and a Huffman coded value?

For example if I see:

```
0xAF 0xFF 0xD9
```

and I have already consumed the bits in `[0xA]`, how can I tell if the next `0xF` is padded or should be decoded?

This is from the JPEG Spec:

> F.1.2.3 Byte stuffing
>
> In order to provide code space for marker codes
>   which can be located in the compressed image data without decoding,
>   byte stuffing is used.
>
> Whenever, in the course of normal encoding, the
>   byte value X’FF’ is created in the code string, a X’00’ byte is
>   stuffed into the code string. If a X’00’ byte is detected after a
>   X’FF’ byte, the decoder must discard it. If the byte is not zero, a
>   marker has been detected, and shall be interpreted to the extent
>   needed to complete the decoding of the scan.
>
> Byte alignment of markers
>   is achieved by padding incomplete bytes with 1-bits. If padding with
>   1-bits creates a X’FF’ value, a zero byte is stuffed before adding the
>   marker.

Answer (score 3):

There are only two possibilities for an FF value in the compressed data stream.

1. Restart Marker; or
2. FF00 representing FF.

If you are decoding a stream, you will know from the restart interval when to expect a restart marker. When you hit the point in decoding where you should find a restart marker, you discard the remaining bits in the current byte.

Comment: What about if I hit `EOI (0xFF, 0xD9)` before hitting a restart marker?

Comment: Something is wrong with  the data if you hit an EOI market without decoding all the  MCUs.

Comment: [This indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) that use of `DRI` is optional.

Comment: It is. Without at DRI marker, the only time you should have to skip bits to the start of a byte  is at the end of the scan.